# PHP Error: Cannot access private property

Tags: php, session, visibility

I have a class like this:

```php
class Session {
    private Session_Database $db;

    public function __construct(){
        // Instantiate new Database object
        $this->db = new Session_Database();

        // Set handler to overide SESSION
        session_set_save_handler(
            [$this, '_open'],
            [$this, '_close'],
            [$this, '_read'],
            [$this, '_write'],
            [$this, '_destroy'],
            [$this, '_gc']
        );

        // Start the session
        session_start();
    }

    /* ... */

    public function _close(): bool {
        // Close the database connection
        $this->db->close();
        return true;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

I'm seeing this error in the logs:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property `Session::$db` in [line number of `$this->db->close()`]
>
> Stack trace:
> #0 [internal function]: `Session->_close()`
> #1 {main}\n thrown in ...

However when I test the code by stepping through in xdebug it works as expected.

What is going on?

Comment: With `session_set_save_handler()` you make certain methods from your session class callable, but when they are called they are not called from within the session object. Have a look at the [User Contributed Notes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler).

Comment: With a quick test I can't get any errors to be produced: https://3v4l.org/WfN3S

Comment: @KIKOSoftware can you be more specific about which comments in the user-contributed notes that you're referring to? my guess is that the class is being destroyed before `_close()` is even getting called, but when I _test_, that isn't actually what happens.

Comment: @ChrisHaas neither can I but I'm getting these errors in my error log.

Comment: Although not really helpful in any way, looking at Symfony's code they are [accessing private variables](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3ca9f3c796ca32deb3ce9530816fa50a0d4fef34/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php#L401) in the `close` method of their PDO handler. To me your code appears correct.

Comment: Just to ask (sorry), is it possible that it is complaining about something within `Session_Database` instead?

Comment: @ChrisHaas a reasonable thought and thanks for looking at another codebase for refernce, but no. The error message specifically says `Session::$db`. The method `Session_Database::close()` is public and non-static and has only one line: `$this->dbh = null;`. That field is private but it should also be accessible in that method's context.

Comment: This code, as shown, will not produce that error message. I suggest working to create a [mre] and you will likely find the source of your problem that way. Including the actual error message in your question may also help.

Comment: @miken32 thanks for looking at my question. This is an intermittent issue that I can't reproduce at will. I did include the actual error message. I only added formatting and removed the file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### As far as your question, "what is going on?"

This appears to happen if memory is exhausted during the course of a PDO query. I believe it has something to do with the memory used by PDO Buffered queries and the way the PHP internal code frees up memory after memory is exhausted.

I can reproduce the condition you have experienced with the following code, (note: this is using `register_shutdown_function`. Both the session_close code and the `register_shutdown_function` will run after a memory exhausted error):

```php
<?php

class TestingClass
{
    private int $something_private;

    public function getThisDone(): void
    {
        $this->something_private = 0;
    }
}

// get a reference to the testing class
$obj = new TestingClass();

register_shutdown_function(fn() => $obj->getThisDone());

// get a pdo connection and run a query that returns a lot of data
$pdoConnection = get_db_read_connection();
$pdoStatement = $pdoConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM your_table_with_a_lot_of_records LIMIT 100000');
$results = $pdoStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, '\stdClass');
```

And the resulting fatal error:

[image]

#### Note:

I cannot reproduce the error if I simply trigger an out of memory error with string concatenation, like below.

```php
// use code above but replace pdo connection and query with this
while(true)
{
    $data .= str_repeat('#', PHP_INT_MAX);
}
```

#### As far as "why is this happening?"

I don't think it should be. It seems like this is a good candidate for a PHP bug report.